# iOS Development: How to Load a Different XIB on Start

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, load, xib

I was wondering how I could load a different XIB when my application initially loads. Right now when my application loads I just get a black screen because there is no MainWindow.xib. Ideally I want to load a XIB that has a UINavigationController inside of it. Does anyone know how to do this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

In `applicationDidFinishLaunching` you may think to something like

```
UINavigationController* navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];

UIViewController *controller = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"First" bundle:nil];
[ navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:NO];
[controller release];

[window addSubview:navigationController.view];
[window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Of course, it actually depends on what you are planning to do...